# Javascript for of loop errors

Tags: javascript

this is the file I'm using

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": {
      "first": "Paige",
      "last": "Bools"
    },
    "birthDate": "1995-02-04T07:34:45Z",
    "contact": {
      "phone": "8989068955",
      "email": "pbools0@webmd.com"
    },
    "address": {
      "street": "476 Veith Parkway",
      "city": "Cuamba",
      "country": "Mozambique"
    },
    "accessCount": 776,
    "isManager": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    // rest of json
  }
]
```

Bunch of users all there.

> My requirement is like this:
>
> - use a for-loop to iterate over the items in users
> - concatenate the first name and last name and assign to a `name` variable
> - call console.log() with the `name` variable
>
> The function doesn't need to return anything.

I wrote my function like this. But its not working

```
function formatNames() {
  for (name of users)
    var name = users.name.first + users.name.last;
  console.log(name);
}
formatNames();
```

Do u guys see any problem in this function?

Answer (score 0):

The users array doesn’t have a name property, so `users.name.first` and `users.name.last` aren’t going to work.

The for loop is iterating the items in the array, not the names in the array. You can call the variable “name” if you want, but that’s not what it represents and will cause confusion.

Each time through the loop your name variable represents a user. So (leaving the loop variable named “name”) you’d need: `name.name.first`.

If you rename the loop variable to “user” it will make more sense:

```js
for (const user of users) {
  // do stuff with user.name.first
}
```